# Need help figuring out time complexity of this pseudocode

Tags: performance, time-complexity, runtime, pseudocode

I am trying to figure out how many primitive operations there are in this code and how many primitive operations are being executed over the runtime of this algorithm:

[image]

**What have I tried to get the answer so far**

I attempted to write the code out onto a piece of paper and go through it line by line. I separated each line into a cost and times ran section in hopes of figuring it out. I ended with T(O) = 2n +6i which seems incorrect.

Here is a snippet of my work:
[image]

***I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me break this problem into concrete steps so  I can better understand this topic as a whole.***

Comment: hint: what is the value of 'i' each time through the loop?

Comment: How to guess it: the cost of the inner loop is `3*i` and increases linearly with `i`. So the average cost when `i` varies from `1` to `n` is the arithmetic mean of the costs at the two ends of the range `(3*1 + 3*n)/2`. Multiply that by `n` and you get the total cost. What's left is to rework this into an actual proof.

Comment: I is equal to 1 so 2n + 6i can we simplified to 2n+6. Would that be correct?